# I want to add banner in the homepage in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I have created a banner in the joomla2.5 now I want to show that banner in the homepage in a particular div so please tell me the code to this task.

Comment: You have to create it under: *Components -> Banners -> Banners -> New*
and publish it to a module position: *Extensions -> Module Manager -> New -> Banners*.

Answer (score 0):

To show a banner in Joomla is pretty simple if you use the native component of the same name (banner).

If you already have created your banner with it and just want to show it, use the native module associate (mod_banner), and add it to one of the available position of your template.

You can find some tutorials on internet on that subject :

- http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-banners.htm (joomla 3, but the behaviour is almost the same)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_caetSLaTok